# Vector Space Subspace Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Prove
that $W = V$ if and only if $\dim W = \dim V$.

This is what I did:

Suppose $\dim W =\dim V\iff|$basis of $W|=|$basis of $V|$ and since $W  \subseteq V \implies W=V$.

For the converse, if $W=V $ then $\text{basis of} \ W = \text{basis of} \ V$. So $ |$basis of $W|=|$basis of $V|$ and hence $\dim W =\dim V$.

Is this enough? Is it right in the first place? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of the converse looks fine to me - though I'd probably write it as "if $S$ is a basis for $W$ it is also a basis for $V$, hence the dimension of each equals $|S|$ and are thus equal to each other" since your current wording makes it kind of look like bases are unique, whereas we really are choosing a particular basis and saying something about it. But the spirit of it is correct.

I don't follow your first proof, though. The property that $W\subseteq V$ and that $|\text{basis of $W$}|=|\text{basis of $V$}|$ are both true, but it's not clear what reasoning combines them into $V=W$. What you might be getting at is that any basis $S$ for $W$ would be a linearly independent set in $V$. However, given that $V$ has dimension $|S|=\dim W=\dim V$, it follows that any linearly independent set of size $|S|$ is a basis for $V$. This means that any basis for $W$ is a basis for $V$. Then, it follows that $W$ and $V$ are both described as the span of $S$ (i.e. the set of linear combinations of its elements), and are hence equal.